# Why .NET Core 7 WebApi Action Filter adds extra quote marks to string?

Tags: .net-core, json.net, asp.net-core-webapi, json-deserialization

I have this IActionFilter and the message I add to it is "Validation Error", without the quote marks.

When I check the result I get: "Validation Error" with quote marks, basically it is ""Validation Error"".

Is there a way to prevent that an additional pair of quote mark is added?

I already have NewtonSoft added, see the configuration below. I haven't found any configuration option for NewtonSoft related to adding/not adding this extra set of quote marks.

```csharp
public class ValidationExceptionsFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
        if (context.Exception is ArgumentNullException
            or ValidationException
            or DbUpdateException
            or GuardsServiceValueShouldNotBeEqualToException)
        {
            context.Result = new ObjectResult(SourceFormatsServiceResultStatuses.ValidationError)
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            };
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

```csharp
            services.AddControllers(o =>
                {
                    o.Filters.Add<InternalServerErrorExceptionsFilter>();
                    o.Filters.Add<NoSuchEntityExceptionsFilter>();
                    o.Filters.Add<ValidationExceptionsFilter>();
                })
                .AddNewtonsoftJson()
                .AddApplicationPart(typeof(SourceFormatNodeController).Assembly);
```

Comment: Maybe you can explain what it has to do with json and deserialization? Except  .AddNewtonsoftJson()?

Comment: If you are returning a string value **serialized as JSON** (then that string will need to be serialized as a JSON string literal as per the [JSON standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8259#page-8) and the [original JSON proposal](https://json.org), which require string literals to be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: @dbc and that adds the extra quotes, right? If I understand correctly what you suggest getting the extra quote marks (since the whole stuff is considered as JSON - even though I add simple text as error message here, but the framework considers it as JSON) is a normal phenomena and I just have to deal with it at client side.

Comment: @Serge see dbc's comment

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to prevent that an additional pair of quote mark is added?

Yes, you can remove additional `""` quotation mark programmatically by using `Trim`

**Implementation:**

```
context.Result = new ObjectResult(SourceFormatsServiceResultStatuses.ValidationError.Trim('"'))
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
                };
```

**Note:** [`Trim('"')`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=net-7.0) will remove extra `""` from `SourceFormatsServiceResultStatuses.ValidationError` as it will remove all leading and trailing `""` characters from the current string.

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** While I was trying to reproduce your issue, I found some dpendency in your code and I cannot test with your snippet rather I have test within my existing code base.

Comment: In the filter the additional "" is not there yet. If trim would be the obvious solution here I would have done it.

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need any further assistance on it.